# How to read temperature, humidity and light measures with contiki-OS?

Tags: sensors, contiki

I would like to know how to measure temperature, light and humidity with a contiki program.

I'm using a TelosB mote (sky mote), so these three sensors are integrated in the mote itself.

PS: I'm working on Contiki-OS 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the light and temperature sensors you will need to add the next:

```
#include "dev/sht11-sensor.h"
#include "dev/light-sensor.h"
```

Then you can use the next functions:

```
static int
get_light(void)
{
  return 10 * light_sensor.value(LIGHT_SENSOR_PHOTOSYNTHETIC) / 7;
}

static int
get_temp(void)
{
  return ((sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP) / 10) - 396) / 10;
}
```

For instance, a minimum application to show the values of those sensors would be:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "dev/sht11-sensor.h"
#include "dev/light-sensor.h"
#include "dev/leds.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//Declare the process
PROCESS(send_sensor_info_process, "Print the Sensors Information");

//Make the process start when the module is loaded
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&send_sensor_info_process);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int
get_light(void)
{
  return 10 * light_sensor.value(LIGHT_SENSOR_PHOTOSYNTHETIC) / 7;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int
get_temp(void)
{
  return ((sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP) / 10) - 396) / 10;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//Define the process code
PROCESS_THREAD(send_sensor_info_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  SENSORS_ACTIVATE(light_sensor);
  SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
  printf("Light: %d \n", get_light());
  printf("Temperature: %d \n", get_temp());

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain these formulas : `10 * light_sensor.value(LIGHT_SENSOR_PHOTOSYNTHETIC) / 7` and `((sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP) / 10) - 396) / 10` ?

Comment: You can get those formulas in the datasheets of the sensors available in the TelosB mote. For instante, the temperature sensor is the [SHT11 sensor](http://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT1x_Datasheet_V5.pdf)

If you check it out, there is a formula that explains how to compute the temperature with the sensor like:

`T = d1 + d2*sensorReading`

You can get the values of d1 and d2 in the table available in the datasheet. You can get the formula of the light sensor in the corresponding sensor specification.