# Contiki OS : How to read from GIO pin of SKY-mote

Tags: c, sensors, contiki

I connected external sensors in to the GIO port of sky mote. How to get the data from the GIO pin of sky mote.

PS : I am using contiki os

```
P2DIR&= ~0x08; // set the port as input
P2SEL &= ~0x08;                  
P2REN |=  0x08;               
if( (P2IN & 0x08) == 0)
{
 SEND_STRING(&s->sout,"UP");
}
else
{
 SEND_STRING(&s->sout,"Down");
}
```

Help me how to read data from the GIO pin of sky mote in contiki os

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this previous question of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047965/how-to-read-temperature-humidity-and-light-measures-with-contiki-os

Comment: I connected external sensor to the GIO pin of the sky mote. I want to read data from the GIO pin.

Comment: You have configured P2 but reading from P1.

Comment: sorry its my mistake. Is it possible to add the above code snippet to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047965/how-to-read-temperature-humidity-and-light-measures-with-contiki-os this code

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to get the GIO2 OF SKY-MOTE

```
P2DIR&= ~0x08; // set the port as input
P2SEL &= ~0x08;                  
P2REN |=  0x08;               
if( (P2IN & 0x08) == 0)
{
 SEND_STRING(&s->sout,"UP");
}
else
{
 SEND_STRING(&s->sout,"Down");
}
```